# Get Down to meaning?

Tags: meaning

In Inside out animation Riley says :
And... we’re out. That’s what I’m talking about: another perfect day! Nice job everybody! 
What Does Get Down To means :

> Let’s **get** those memories **down to** Long Term.

Comment: I think Joy says that, after Riley has gone to sleep.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***Let's get those memories down to Long Term*** is an informal way of saying ***Let's send those memories to Long Term***.

This is a typical way of communicating in a company or organization. It comes from a time when a department of a company would send documents to a different department on a different floor of an office building. It's typical to hear phrases like ***get this up to*** or ***get this down to*** when referring to inter-departmental communications. The movie treats the human body as a company of sorts, with different departments. It makes sense that the different parts of the body would communicate in a way similar to a corporate office.

Comment: Can you give us examples : 1) Get the books up to the library. 2) Get the books down to the library. What is the difference here ???

Comment: That would depend on whether the library is above or below you, either physically or metaphorically.  "Get these papers up to head office" because head office is above my department in the hierarchy. "Get these books down to the library." because the library is a floor below my office. In the movie, "Long-term Storage" is both physical and metaphorically "below" the control room where Joy works.

Comment: Get them down to the basement long storage: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/42/Oxford_-_Jesus_College_-_0531.jpg

Comment: I just found some different meaning Am I Right ? 1) This is one of the most expensive and also more convenient ways to get down to London. (Get down to = Go to London) 2)  Books can also be posted to you throughout the UK and Europe if you can't get up to London. (Get up to = Go to London)

Comment: Sure, those are common ways of saying ***go to London***. ***Get this up to*** and ***Get this down to*** can refer to being north or south of London. It can also refer to elevation. If you live in the mountains, everything might be ***down*** to you. Some people always say ***get this down to*** and never say ***get this up to***, and vice-versa. The two phrases can really be used interchangeably, and it doesn't have to make sense physically or metaphorically to be considered an acceptable use.

Comment: @JamesK - It _might_ depend on what floor your on, but these prepositions are also flexible enough that I could use _up to_ or _down to_ even if the destination was on the same floor (much as we might say that the donut shop is either _up the street_ or _down the street_, even if the road is flat and runs east-west).

Answer (score 1):

I believe this sentence means "Let's store these memories in our long term memory", i.e. let's treasure today's events and remember them for a long time.